# How does the hardness of Subset Sum instances depend on their density?

Tags: complexity-theory

The density of a Subset Sum instance $S = \{ s_1, \dots, s_n \}$ of size $n$ is defined as

$\qquad\displaystyle d(S) = \frac{|S|}{\log_2(\max_{s \in S} |s|)}$.

Why is the hardness of Subset-Sum dependent on its density?

Comment: While you're at it, you could define what you intend "hardness" to mean.

Comment: Experts, please suggest proper (new) tags. I know that there is a body of research dealing with such phase transitions (?) but I don't know what the proper keywords are.

Comment: Where do you get the figure 0.9408 from? I suspect some background is missing here.

Comment: 1) I tried to put your "answer" into a formula. Is that what you meant? 2) You seem to have read something. Which paper is it? Please give [proper attribution](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/98).

Comment: Given the amount of questions and lack of reaction so far, is this too unclear? Community votes, please!

Comment: see [here](http://www.farcaster.com/papers/sm-thesis/node30.html)

Comment: The link supplied A.Schulz mentions an attack that word whenever $d<0.9408$. The attack works for *all* instances. There are no intractable instances with this density.

Comment: I voted to close. I'm happy to retract my vote (or vote to open) if the question is edited to up to the standards (i.e., where is the magical number coming from? What do you think?).

Comment: What is an "intractable instance"? Do you actually mean, "Is it possible for Subset Sum to be intractable on the set of all instances of less density less than 0.9408?"